# How to add information automaticlly in table

Tags: javascript, html

I have three dialog box, one for input name, for input last name, and for input points. I'm trying to make program that will automatically put my inputs in new table on same page. So when I input name program automaticlly put name on table, same for name and points. And in table I have column "requirements". If user input that he have more then 35 points in column "requirements" need to print automaticlly "YES" or if he has lower then 35 program need to print "NO"

Here is how I started, I made table and three input dialogs, but this thing with automatic print and checking points is not going very well:

```
<form>
 Name: <input type="text" id="name"/><br/>
 Last name: <input type="text" id="last"/><br/>
 Points: <input type="number" id="age"/><br/>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button><br></form>
 <div id="a"></div>
 </form>

<table>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}
</style>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last name</th>
<th>Points</th>
<th>Requirements</th>
</tr>
```

I tried with:

```
$("th i ").click(function () {
var index = $(this).parent().index();
$("tr").each(function () {
$(this).find("input").val($(this).find("td:eq(" + index + ") input").val());
$(this).find("select").val($(this).find("td:eq(" + index + ") 
select").val())
})
})
```

Comment: Please add the JavaScript you have tried out so far.

Comment: And please take the time to properly format and indent your code to a readable format before posting.

Comment: If you dont know how to help me, please, stop posting usless comments. Wise man...

Answer (score 0):

Best way to finish this is from .js file... Make one .js file and include it in html with `<script src="name.js" type="module"></script>`

In that name.js file you need to find your elements with **querySelector** or **getElementById** ... example:

```js
const inputName=document.getElementById("name");
const inputLast=document.getElementById("last");
const inputPts=document.getElementById("age");
const buttonName=documen.getElementById("btn");

buttonName.onclick=(ev)=>createTable(ev.target);

function createTable(buttonName)
{

const getTable=document.querySelector("table");
//create table here <trow><th>...</th></trow>
//create table here <trow><td>...</td></trow>

//find a div with id="a" 

const getDiv=document.getElementById("a");
if(inputPts.value>35)
{
getDiv.innerHTML="YES";
}
else
{
getDiv.innerHTML="NO";
}

}
```